# Anaconda Kickstart File is Cached

Tags: linux, caching, redhat, anaconda

I'm upgrading an HP server from Redhat5 to Redhat6, but my kickstart file is using 'cciss' type drives and the Anaconda installer is looking for 'sda', thus throwing a 'disk not found for clearpart' error. The kickstart file is on an NFS share.

I edited the kickstart file, but it looks like Anaconda is caching it somewhere on the machine and using it every time I try to restart the installation process. I managed to boot again into Redhat5 and remove /root/anaconda-ks.cfg. But that didn't do the trick. Where is the ks file cached?

Cheers
Remus

Comment: I think it's under /tmp/ks.cfg in the chroot-ed pre-installation environment. I'll have to confirm this

Answer (score 1):

it was under /tmp/ks.cfg for this distro
My problem was that the file was cached at the Riverbed level.